# Button doesn't work - Selenium

Tags: java, events, button, selenium, mouseevent

By clicking on the button, it should call another class to fill some fields, but it didn't work.

I was testing the button with the methods mouseOver, mouseDown, mouseUp, mouseOut and they worked. 
The code:

```
public class PopupMatricula extends BABasicFormWrapper{

public void selecionarMatricula(String idBotao, IComandoTeste comando) throws Exception{

    //clica para invocar popup
    click(idBotao);


    selenium.waitForPopUp("_blank", "30000");
    selenium.selectWindow("_blank");

    SeleniumUtil.getInstance().aumentarJanela();


    selenium.selectWindow("_blank");

    if(selenium.isElementPresent("//div[contains(@id, 'ac_btn_toggler_bemimovel_r_popup')]//input[contains(@src, 'abToggleShow.gif')]")){
        click(getBotaoToggle());
    }

    click("//input[contains(@src, 'cmdpesquisar.gif')]");

    selenium.mouseOver("//div[contains(@id, 'ac_grd_bemimovel_r_popup')]//table//tbody/tr["+pesquisaGrid("ac_grd_bemimovel_r_popup", comando)+ "]//td/input[contains(@src, 'gridselecionar.gif')]");        
    aguardarAjax();
    aguardar();
    selenium.mouseDown("//div[contains(@id, 'ac_grd_bemimovel_r_popup')]//table//tbody/tr["+pesquisaGrid("ac_grd_bemimovel_r_popup", comando)+ "]//td/input[contains(@src, 'gridselecionar_over.gif')]");
    aguardarAjax();
    aguardar();
    selenium.mouseUp("//div[contains(@id, 'ac_grd_bemimovel_r_popup')]//table//tbody/tr["+pesquisaGrid("ac_grd_bemimovel_r_popup", comando)+ "]//td/input[contains(@src, 'gridselecionar_over.gif')]");

//      selenium.mouseOut("//div[contains(@id, 'ac_grd_bemimovel_r_popup')]//table//tbody/tr["+pesquisaGrid("ac_grd_bemimovel_r_popup", comando)+ "]//td/input[contains(@src, 'gridselecionar_over.gif')]");

    aguardarAjax();
    Thread.sleep(1500);


    new Portal2Helper().selecionarJanelaPrincipal();

}
```

I apreciate the help.

Comment: Well on what browser? On what site? What happens? What doesn't happen? What errors do you get? **Help us to help you**....

Comment: The class PopupMatricula has a button from a form in the class BABasicFormWrapper. Then, some fields in the form should be completed by clicking on the button, but it doesn't work.
It's not shown a message of error, just the mouse event doesn't happen.
The browser is Firefox.

Comment: It's probably some javascript which webdriver isn't firing. Can you post the html code of the button? That will help us figure out what's going wrong. P.S. When you respond to comments, it's best to edit your question to include the new information. That way, any new reader can see the entire situation without having to scan through all the comments (and it makes it all more readable).